# Ubuntu 16.04 ethernet driver not found in lenovo p52

Tags: 16.04

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my lenovo p52 . It is not detecting the network(ethernet)
Can anyone please help

Comment: have to tried to check if ethernet adapter is detected by the OS? try `ifconfig -a` and see if `eth0` is listed.

Comment: Install a later version (18.04)? The P52 is a rather recent machine...